# Quicktime player "frame by frame" mode cannot mapping OpenCV cap.read() "frame by frame"

Tags: opencv, quicktime

I play my video by Quicktime player frame by frame , and using  OpenCV cap.read() frame by frame,
but it seems not mapping

i had tried the openCV cap.set() CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES
seens have similary issue ,is it the same issue on Quicktime player ?

Comment: frame number not mapping

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre]